# Make jQuery mobile button with icon and no text the same height as buttons with text

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

This html/css:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-right">Left</a>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
```

Produces this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

Comment: Could you post the CSS you've got?  I've a couple of ideas but would be good to see what you've tried already.

Comment: Only off the shelf jQuery mobile so far.

Comment: Okay, cool.  Try setting the lineheight attribute to 1em and see if that works.

Comment: @OllyJohn It got closer but still a little short. I would've thought that would have worked.

Comment: Have a play with the numbers until it's right then.  The button's probably got some defaulted padding on the one with the text so it'll be 1em plus x amount of pixels.  Once you've got the number pinned, give me a shout and I'll write it up into a formal answer.

Comment: @OllyJohn em doesn't seem to work because changing font size will change the buttons at different rates. Here's a fiddle if you want to figure it out: http://jsfiddle.net/tonyleif/7maf623j/. I'll give you credit if you do.

Comment: I'll take a look for you :)

Comment: I just tried it using the height attribute instead of line-height and it worked fine - have a look and if you're happy with it then I'll write it up for you

Comment: @OllyJohn Did you zoom? It doesn't seem to work if you change the page zoom.

Comment: Yeah, I did and it worked fine..  What browser are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97010/discussion-between-tony-l-and-olly-john).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-right">Left</a>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext">ThisWontBeVisible</a>
```

The class `ui-btn-icon-notext` will remove the text ("ThisWontBeVisible") within the `<a>`. However, if there is no text within the `<a>`, it will shrink the button to a short height. Seems like a hack but also likely the simplest way to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting the `height` attribute to `1em` on all of your `.ui-btn` elements, or any height greated than 1em.  This will set them all to the same height regardless of whether they have text inside them or not.

Comment: I have confirmed this also works. It should be noted that it will change the heights of all buttons with .ui-btn and not just the one in question.

Comment: Yep, providing the uniformity you were asking for in the question with minimal fuss and processing.